# injection from R^d to [0,1]^d

Tags: r, optimization, constraints

I'm trying to optimise a function over some weights, that should all be positive and add up to one.

Thus, i'm transforming the (unconstrained) values through the function :

```
# Transformation of parameters (FOR ONLY 3 PARAMETRES)
g <- function(v) {
  # Ensure they in [0,1]
  v <- 1/(1+exp(v))
  # Ensure they add up to 1
  v <- c( v[1], v[2] * (1-v[1]) )
  u <- c(v, 1-sum(v))
  u
}
```

How can i generalise this to $d$ parameters instead of only 3 ?

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways, but in general we can recognize two main steps: making the values nonnegative (by taking absolute value, squaring, etc.) and normalizing to sum to one. One pretty natural option would be

```
g <- function(v) abs(v) / sum(abs(v))
g(1:5)
# [1] 0.06666667 0.13333333 0.20000000 0.26666667 0.33333333
sum(g(1:5))
# [1] 1
```

where I chose to use `abs` as to make the weights nonnegative, while `x / sum(x)` is the way to make the resulting vector to sum to one.

If you wish the input to have one dimension less, you may add an extra value inside the function. Since it's a part of optimization, I don't think you want this value to be random. So, it may be either fixed, or dependent in `v` in a deterministic way. So, we may use, e.g.,

```
g <- function(v) {
  v <- c(v, mean(v))
  abs(v) / sum(abs(v))
}
g(1:4)
# [1] 0.08 0.16 0.24 0.32 0.20
sum(g(1:4))
# [1] 1
```

But it's most likely important in your problem what this extra value is and even in which position of the output vector it is, so I suggest to make sure it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But since the "sum up to one" constraint shrikens by one dimension the problem, i'd like the input value (the one i'm optimising on) to be one dimension smaller. But i'll definitely try your's.

Comment: yeah, this way it does not make sens to just take the mean. What would make sens is to take "The complement to one" but since we are dividing by the sum, it's not posible anymore.

Comment: @lrnv, without additional assumptions (i.e., on the length of `v` and the range of its elements) one cannot avoid division by the sum.